# Templated method pointer - can't match pointer for function argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

I am making a method pointer wrapper like this:

```
template<typename OBJECT, typename... ARGS>
method_wrapper<ARGS...> _getWrapper(OBJECT* object, void (OBJECT::*method)(ARGS...))
{
    //irrelevant
}
```

The problem is right at the calling of `_getWrapper`:

```
class TestClass
{

    void TestMethod(int a, float b, bool c)
    {
        std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<b<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
TestClass testObj;

method_wrapper<int, float, bool> wrap = _getWrapper<int, float, bool>(&testObj, TestClass::TestMethod);

wrap.callInternal(1000, 3.14, true);

//...

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Not matter in what way I try to pass the arguments in _getWrapper, it still tells me:

> no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list

Doesn't `OBJECT::*method` match `TestClass::TestMethod` directly? I also tried `&TestClass::TestMethod`, doesn't match either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifying the template arguments explicitly when invoking `_getWrapper`, and the first one is specifed as `int` for template parameter `OBJECT`, which is wrong. Because member pointers can't refer into non-class type.

Change

```
_getWrapper<int, float, bool>(&testObj, TestClass::TestMethod)
```

to

```
_getWrapper<TestClass, int, float, bool>(&testObj, &TestClass::TestMethod)
//          ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Note you can just rely on [template type deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), e.g.

```
_getWrapper(&testObj, &TestClass::TestMethod)
```

BTW: For taking address from members you should always use `&` for it.
BTW: I suppose `TestClass::TestMethod` is `public`.